# How to read static data file in Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm a beginner with Jetpack Compose. I want to include a data file with my app (xml, csv or similar) that will never change. I want to read this file when the app starts, and instantiate a list of objects. Ultimately, I want the user to be able to search this list, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

I could hard-code these objects, but as the list is a few hundred objects, it seems wiser to read the data from a file rather than define them all in code.

Where should I put this file in my project? How can I read from this file (ideally with some sort of existing csv/xml parser)? Where is a good place to perform this read - would the onCreate function of my activity be appropriate?

I'm also open to other suggestions if this approach is misguided.

Comment: "Where should I put this file in my project?" -- probably as an asset, in an `assets/` directory you create as a peer of `java/`, `res/`, etc. You can call `getAssets()` on a `Context` to get an `AssetManager`, and from there you can get an `InputStream` to pass to your preferred parser (JSON, XML, CSV, whatever). "would the onCreate function of my activity be appropriate?" -- by default, that will freeze the UI during the read operation.

Comment: I found this similar question with an excellent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70644915/display-asset-text-file-in-composable-function-using-kotlin-jetpack-compose